# Add values to a list of list with for loop and .append in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, for-loop, indexing, append

I have a dataframe composed by 3 columns which rappresent coordinates of single positions and time of the recorded position :

```
X           Y         MonthYear
2945.13    2588.46    Oct2020
2955.13    2523.36    Oct2020
2945.12    2534.36    Oct2020
....
2935.15    2584.37    Nov2020
2945.12    2523.36    Nov2020
....
2912.17    2548.56    Dec2020
....
2912.17    2548.56    Jan2021
...
```

I would like to create a list of list containing the coordinates X Y for each month, respectively.

This is my partial code:

```
# I create an empty list of list for each month to fill with coordiantes X Y 
# list of list: one list for each month within the dataframe

points_months = [[] for _ in range(len(pd.unique(XY_22225['MonthYear'])))] 
XY_22225 = XY_22225.reset_index()  # make sure indexes pair with number of rows
```

Now i want to fill such lists using a for loop:

```
for index, row in XY_22225.iterrows():
    current_point = (row['X'], row['Y']) # To combine X Y coordinates
    points_months[row['MonthYear']-1].append(current_point) # here I bind each X Y to the corresponding month
```

However this message of error appears : `IndexError: list index out of range`

Can you help me? Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity? I assumed a list of `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]` for each month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and conversion [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('MonthYear', sort=False)[['X', 'Y']]
         .apply(lambda g: g.to_numpy().tolist())
      )
```

Output:

```
MonthYear
Oct2020    [[2945.13, 2588.46], [2955.13, 2523.36], [2945...
Nov2020             [[2935.15, 2584.37], [2945.12, 2523.36]]
Dec2020                                 [[2912.17, 2548.56]]
Jan2021                                 [[2912.17, 2548.56]]
```

Or, for a dictionary:

```
out = {year_month: g.to_numpy().tolist() for year_month, g in
       df.groupby('MonthYear', sort=False)[['X', 'Y']]}
```

Output:

```
{'Oct2020': [[2945.13, 2588.46], [2955.13, 2523.36], [2945.12, 2534.36]],
 'Nov2020': [[2935.15, 2584.37], [2945.12, 2523.36]],
 'Dec2020': [[2912.17, 2548.56]],
 'Jan2021': [[2912.17, 2548.56]]}
```